# Fit a mongo users collection within a normal distribution

Tags: node.js, mongodb, normal-distribution

I have a mongo collection that keeps users characteristics such as age, employment status, etc. as displayed below:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0bfe85a960f54c082c1bdd"},
"user_id":"5f0809e5df54cbb9a41a3f12",
"age":30,
"sex":2,
"employment":1,
"education":3
}
```

I would like to find though the outlier users that are far away from the typical user as this is shaped by the various docs within the collection.
In order to achieve this, I would like to fit the collection within the normal distribution. I have noticed the node library `gaussian-fit` available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaussian-fit.
My understanding is that in the data variable I should pass the values of each one of the fields of the collection...? Is there a way to general conclude about a collection and its data how they are distributed ?

Comment: What do you like to check for normal distribution? The 'age' has not Gaussian distribution (it is rather some kind of pyramid). The 'sex' is typically 50/50 - Gauss would be an overkill. The [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/index.html) operator may help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check how the different variables fields were distributed I used Mongo Atlas, deployed the collections in a cluster, and then used Charts to create histograms either using bins or not to check how they were distributed and gained a visualized picture of them like below:

[image]